# mysql - getting fieldname from a function

Tags: mysql

I have a table with different fieldnames for different weeks like this:

```
+-----+--------+--------+
| uid | hours0 | hours1 |
+-----+--------+--------+
| 1   |  15    |   20   |
+-----+--------+--------+
| 2   |  12    |   7    |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

hours0 is the number of hours a member has in an even week
hours1 is the number of hours a member has in an odd week

So I need to find out if the current week is odd or even and take the correct column.

in an even week it would be

```
SELECT hours0 AS hours FROM mytable WHERE uid = 1;
```

and if the current week has an odd weeknumber it would be

```
SELECT hours1 AS hours FROM mytable WHERE uid = 1;
```

But with mysql it is possible to find out with WEEK(CURDATE())%2 if the current week ist odd (1) or even (0) - so I can write it like that:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN WEEK(CURDATE())%2=0 THEN hours0 ELSE hours1 END AS hours FROM mytable WHERE uid=1;
```

And it always will return the correct number of hours (in this case 15 for an even and 20 for an odd weeknumber. But since my real query is much more complicated I would like to write a SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('hours',WEEK(CURDATE())%2) as hours FROM mytable WHERE uid=1;
```

But my statement returns hours0 instead of 15 in an even week an hours1 instead of 20 in an odd week. So I would need a way to tell mysql that it should not return hours0 but the column hours0 where hours0 is concatet dynamically.

Comment: I think this would be simplified by storing hours in a single column

Comment: yeah, if the hours would be the same for odd and even weeks

Comment: Regardless of that, it would be simpler. If you need to know whether a week is odd or even, either store the week or a odd/even flag in a separate column.

Comment: I need to know if the current week is odd or even and then I take the odd or the even value of hours. If we have currently week 4 of the year I want to know the even number of hours. In week 5 the odd number.